# Adding nested dictionaries in Python from yield

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

If I do something like this:

```
x1={'Count': 11, 'Name': 'Andrew'}
x2={'Count': 14, 'Name': 'Matt'}
x3={'Count': 17, 'Name': 'Devin'}
x4={'Count': 20, 'Name': 'Andrew'}
x1

vars=[x1,x2,x3,x4]
for i in vars:
    my_dict[i[group_by_column]]=i
my_dict
```

Then I get:

```
defaultdict(int,
            {'Andrew': {'Count': 20, 'Name': 'Andrew'},
             'Devin': {'Count': 17, 'Name': 'Devin'},
             'Geoff': {'Count': 10, 'Name': 'Geoff'},
             'Matt': {'Count': 14, 'Name': 'Matt'}})
```

Which is exactly what I want.

However, when I try to replicate this from an object that is has a `yield` built into it, it keeps overwriting very value in the dictionary. For example, `cast_record_stream` is a function result that yields the following dictionaries as requested:

```
{'Count': 11, 'Name': 'Andrew'}
{'Count': 14, 'Name': 'Matt'}
{'Count': 17, 'Name': 'Devin'}
{'Count': 20, 'Name': 'Andrew'}
{'Count': 5, 'Name': 'Geoff'}
{'Count': 10, 'Name': 'Geoff'}
```

So then when I run this function it comes out wrong:

```
for line in cast_record_stream:
    record_name=line['Name']
    my_dict[record_name]=line

    defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Devin': {'Count': 10, 'Name': 'Geoff'}, 
'Matt': {'Count': 10, 'Name': 'Geoff'}, 
'Geoff': {'Count': 10, 'Name': 'Geoff'}, 
'Andrew': {'Count': 10, 'Name': 'Geoff'}})
```

Am I creating a problem here that I can't see? I figured it would just add one value at a time.

Comment: It might help to show your code with the `yield` in question.

Comment: It's multiple functions chained together so it would just get confusing. The important part is that it yields each of the dictionaries I listed above, some of which have a repeated `Name`

Comment: My guess: `cast_record_stream` modifies and yields _the same_ dictionary over an over again. Make sure to create a new dict before yielding.

Comment: No, if I add a line `print line` after calling the last loop, it'll produce a different dictionary at each iteration.

Comment: It prints a "different" (looking) dict then because you did not change them before printing. Post your generator function, I am roughly 99.7% sure that that's the problem.

Comment: BTW, why are you using a `defaultdict(int)` if you are mapping strings to dicts? Does not make any sense. Use a `defaultdict(dict)` or just a plain `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. Here is a full reproduction, except that it works perfectly. This shows that the ideas you described in your OP are correct, and you have some other bug in the real code.

```
cast_list = [
    {'Count': 11, 'Name': 'Andrew'},
    {'Count': 14, 'Name': 'Matt'},
    {'Count': 17, 'Name': 'Devin'},
    {'Count': 20, 'Name': 'Andrew'},
    {'Count': 5, 'Name': 'Geoff'},
    {'Count': 10, 'Name': 'Geoff'},
]

def cast_record_stream():
    for record in cast_list:
        yield record

from collections import defaultdict
d = {}
for record in cast_record_stream():
    print record
    d[record['Name']] = record
print d
```

Per the discussion in comments below, I think you are storing record_name=line['Name'] sometimes, but it does not get updated sometimes, because you are iterating over something that you should not, possibly resulting in a for loop that never executes the line which would update record_name.

Comment: So I'm trying this and it's not working.....it doesn't recognize `cast_record_stream` as a function because in my code it's an object storing the `yield` from the previous function

Comment: I though you said it was a generator function. If that's the one yield, then you can't iterate over it.  You just add that one yield, and you're done, for now.  There is an iteration somewhere else (or else it would be silly to have a generator), and that's where you can build the full dict.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, sorry. I'm new to python and all i can say is that `cast_recode_stream` is not a function, but storage of the `yield` results of a previous function. I don't want to post everything because this is training for something and I worry about privacy issues.

Comment: If so, then what you are iterating over is NOT what you think you are iterating over.  Look at it in a debugger as you step over that part of the code.

Comment: I (think) I understand what `yield` does, so how do I grab each object it produces in an iterable fashion and store it in a dictionary?

Comment: Something else iterates, causing the yield multiple times.  Each time, you get to pick up that ONE RESULT and add just that one entry to the dictionary. If I understand what you're saying correctly.

Comment: That would be fine except my expectation is that the "ONE RESULT" would change with each run of the loop, whereas it seems to be using the SAME RESULT for each run of the loop. What gives?

Comment: That's probably because you are using a variable that doesn't get updated when you try to iterate over something that you can't iterate over. Step through it in a debugger. The record will change each time, but you aren't using the new record for some reason (which didn't make it into the posted question)

Answer (score -1):

A couple of issues. First, cast_record_stream is a function, I assume, so your first line should be

```
for line in cast_record_stream():
```

Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. If your iterator returns two Geoffs, the latter will always overwrite the former. If you expect to have duplicate Names, you probably should consider a different method of storing your data than a dictionary.

R

Comment: It's a function result that has all of the individual dictionaries, but these come up one at a time thanks to the `yield` piece

Comment: Note how the key in `'Devin': {'Count': 10, 'Name': 'Geoff'}` is different from the name in the dict. The dicts come out of the generator with the right (distinct) names, but they are all changed before they are printed. Again, my guess is that those are all pointing to the same dict instance.